# Python - issue with reading in hex byte

Tags: python, hex, byte

I am reading in a file containing hex bytes I believe, here is what i wrote:

```
def ByteToHexToDec( byteStr ):
    hex_list = [ "%02X" % ord(x) if "\\x" in r"%r" % x else x for x in byteStr];
    return hex_list;

with open("file.z","rb") as lines:
    for line in lines:
        print ByteToHexToDec(line);
```

and here is what it returned:

```
['04', '80', 'e', '06', 'C0', 'l', '06', 'F0', ',', '02', '00', 'w', '06', 'F0', 'r', '06', 'C0', 'd', '02', '10', '\n']
```

I am pretty sure this says hello world (or something very similar), and I know the hex of 'hello world' is this:

```
480065006C006C006F00200077006F0072006C00640021
```

If you see closely, the '48' matches with the first two element in the hex_list except the zeros being in the way, and the letter e has hex value 65...

So am is there some error with the bytes in the file? or am I reading in the bytes wrongly?

Thanks

The file can be downloaded here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B84_Z1V4nj9SS0x4MlR0a2poMkE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The output is correct for the file contents.

Comment: I'm not sure how you produced the file, but you have `0480` at the start, not `4800`, in that file. The `e` is correctly saved as a `65` byte, followed by two bytes that make for the next `l` as `06c0`. I suspect you forgot to pad your bytes when you *created* the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every other byte in your file is padded out with a starting and trailing `0`:

- `H` is `04 80` instead of `48`
- `e` is `65` (correct)
- `l` is `06 c0` instead of `6c`
- `l` is `6c` (correct)
- `o` is `06 f0` instead of `6f`
- `,` is `2c` (correct)
- (space) is `02 00` instead of `20`

etc.

If you wanted that to turn back into `Hello, world`, you'll have to repair that breakage:

```
def repairbroken(bytestr):
    bytestr = iter(bytestr)
    for byte1, byte2, byte3 in zip(*([bytestr] * 3)):
        # character 1 is bits 4-7 in the first byte and bits 0-3 in the second
        char1 = chr((ord(byte1) & 0xff) << 4 | (ord(byte2) & 0xff) >> 4)
        yield char1
        yield byte3
```

Demo:

```
>>> binary = '\x04\x80e\x06\xc0l\x06\xf0,\x02\x00w\x06\xf0r\x06\xc0d\x02\x10\n'
>>> print ''.join(repairbroken(binary))
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Or it could be packed 12-bit characters. Not sure what the high bits would contain though.

Comment: if it is packed as 12-bit, how would I read the bytes in differently?

Comment: @WerdnaKof: you'd still have to read 3 bytes at a time and split those 24 bits out to chunks of 12. It'll depend on what's in those top 4 bits each time what you do with them; here I just discard the ignore the 4 bits each time.

Comment: @WerdnaKof: if the top 4 bits are used for anything, it isn't clear exactly what those bits are used for and how that'd map to characters.

Comment: ok I think I get it now, so I convert the first byte into binary form as such:
00000100 10000000 01100101
then chop in halves,
000001001000      000001100101
which gives me 48 and 65! (Thanks for the help)

Comment: @WerdnaKof: Exactly. But if there are bits set in those first nibbles (4-bit groups) and you get values > 255, you'll have to figure out what that is supposed to map to.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the file in hex:

```
$ od -t x1z -w16 file.z 
0000000 04 80 65 06 c0 6c 06 f0 2c 02 00 77 06 f0 72 06  >..e..l..,..w..r.<
0000020 c0 64 02 10 0a                                   >.d...<
0000025
```

What are you attempting?

```
$ echo 'hello world' | od -t x1z -w12 
0000000 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 0a  >hello world.<
0000014
```

Note hexlify/unhexlify in the binascii module
https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html

Comment: hmm, when I read it without converting, I get this:
['\x04', '\x80', 'e', '\x06', '\xc0', 'l', '\x06', '\xf0', ',', '\x02', '\x00', 'w', '\x06', '\xf0', 'r', '\x06', '\xc0', 'd', '\x02', '\x10', '\n']

I am simply trying to convert these hex bytes into decimal (which I can do), but the problem they don't come out as hello world.

Comment: Check Martijn's reply, then the last line in mine here.